# Why is method of image charges not working?

Tags: electrostatics, method-of-images

suppose a situation with two infinite thin conducting planes in front of each other with one of them having a charge density σ
[image]

it can be clearly predicted that the induced charge density on neutral conductor must be uniform on one side. so no matter what charge density in induced on neutral conductor, it results in a zero electric field due to itself anywhere outside it. so net electric field must be $\sigma/2\epsilon$.

[image]

---

### but, using method of image charges

the net electric field comes to be $\sigma/\epsilon$
[image]

*Is method of charges not valid here?*

*or, is the first interpretation for calculating field wrong?*

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543880/

Comment: I cannot find out why you assume $\sigma/2$  on the two sides of the charged plate?

Comment: @trula it can be proved by gauss law and making electric field inside conductor = 0. But no matter what the distribution is, as long as its uniform, it will give same net electric field outside. So it doesn't matter

Comment: This is only true if zee one plate is completely isolated, not if you have a second conductor nearby

Comment: why does another conductor affect it?